# Re: Stewart & Tall, "Complex Analysis" ($2^\text{nd}$ ed. 2018), Proposition 2.45: constructing a family of space-filling curves

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, proof-verification, curves

Here are the statement and proof of the proposition, as they appear in the book:

> Let $\mathbb{U}^2$ be the unit square $\{ x + iy : 0 \le x \le 1, \
> 0 \le y \le 1\}$. [$\ldots$]
>
> PROPOSITION 2.45. Let $\gamma_n : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{U}^2$ be a
>   sequence of continuous paths, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose that:
>
> (i) The sequence of functions $(\gamma_n)$ is uniformly convergent.
>
> (ii) The closure of the union of the images of all $\gamma_n$ is
>   the whole of $\mathbb{U}^2$.
>
> Then the limit
>   $$
> \gamma = \lim_{n\to\infty}\gamma_n
> $$
>   is continuous, and its image is $\mathbb{U}^2$. [$\ldots$]
>
> *Proof.* By condition (i), a basic theorem in real analysis
>   implies that the limit $\gamma$ exists and is continuous.
>
> Let $z \in \mathbb{U}^2$. By condition (ii), for each $m > 0$,
>   $m \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $t_m \in [0, 1]$ and $n_m \in
> \mathbb{N}$ such that
>   \begin{equation}
> \tag{1}\label{ineq:1}
> \left\lvert\gamma_{n_m}(t_m) - z\right\rvert < \frac{1}{m}
> \end{equation}
>   The subsequence $\gamma_{n_m}$ also tends uniformly to $\gamma$. The
>   sequence $(t_m)$ lies in $[0, 1]$ which is closed and bounded, so it
>   has a convergent subsequence, with limit $t_0$. We claim that
>   $\gamma(t_0) = z$. By uniform continuity, if $m$ is large enough,
>   \begin{equation}
> \tag{2}\label{ineq:2}
> \left\lvert\gamma_{n_m}(t_0) - \gamma(t_0)\right\rvert < \frac{1}{m}
> \end{equation}
>   So
>   \begin{equation}
> \tag{3}\label{ineq:3}
> \left\lvert\gamma(t_0) - z\right\rvert < \frac{2}{m}
> \end{equation}
>   for all $m$, so $\gamma(t_0) = z$ as claimed. $\square$

(Tags \eqref{ineq:1}, \eqref{ineq:2}, \eqref{ineq:3} have been
added to make it easier to discuss the proof, and are not in the book.)

Assuming that the sequence $(n_m)_{m\geq1}$ was chosen to be strictly
increasing, it is clear that $\gamma_{n_m}$ tends uniformly to $\gamma$,
as stated.

The next statement is also clearly correct: there exists $t_0 \in [0, 1]$,
and a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers $(m_k)_{k\geq1}$,
such that the subsequence $u_k = t_{m_k}$ tends to $t_0$.

If we write (almost illegibly!) $\sigma_k = \gamma_{n_{m_k}}$, then
$\sigma_k$ also tends uniformly to $\gamma$.

From \eqref{ineq:1}, we have:
\begin{equation}
\tag{4}\label{ineq:4}
\left\lvert\sigma_k(u_k) - z\right\rvert =
\big\lvert\gamma_{n_{m_k}}(t_{m_k}) - z\big\rvert < \frac{1}{m_k}.
\end{equation}

Take any $\epsilon > 0$. By the continuity of $\gamma$ at $t_0$, there
exists $\delta > 0$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\tag{5}\label{ineq:5}
\left\lvert\gamma(t) - \gamma(t_0)\right\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{3}
\text{ if } \left\lvert t - t_0 \right\rvert < \delta.
\end{equation}

Because $u_k \to t_0$ as $k \to \infty$, there exists $K_1$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\tag{6}\label{ineq:6}
\left\lvert u_k - t_0 \right\rvert < \delta \text{ if } k > K_1.
\end{equation}

By \eqref{ineq:5} and \eqref{ineq:6},
\begin{equation}
\tag{7}\label{ineq:7}
\left\lvert\gamma(u_k) - \gamma(t_0)\right\rvert <\frac{\epsilon}{3}
\text{ if } k > K_1.
\end{equation}

Because $\sigma_k \to \gamma$ uniformly as $k \to \infty$, there
exists $K_2$ such that:
\begin{equation*}
\left\lvert\sigma_k(t) - \gamma(t)\right\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{3}
\text{ for all } t \in [0, 1] \text{ if } k > K_2.
\end{equation*}

In particular:
\begin{equation}
\tag{8}\label{ineq:8}
\left\lvert\sigma_k(u_k) - \gamma(u_k)\right\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{3}
\text{ if } k > K_2.
\end{equation}

By \eqref{ineq:4}, because $m_k \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$, there
exists $K_3$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\tag{9}\label{ineq:9}
\left\lvert\sigma_k(u_k) - z\right\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{3}
\text{ if } k > K_3.
\end{equation}

By \eqref{ineq:7}, \eqref{ineq:8} and \eqref{ineq:9}, taking any $k > \max\{K_1, K_2, K_3\}$,
\begin{equation*}
\left\lvert\gamma(t_0) - z\right\rvert < \epsilon.
\end{equation*}

Because $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\gamma(t_0) = z$,
as claimed. $\square$

This proof could be accused of being tiresomely pedantic, and maybe
even juvenile!  It is certainly longer and more cluttered with
notation than the proof in the book; but at least I think I can see
that it is valid. (Is it, though?)

In contrast, although I have opened the book
several times in the last few days, and stared intently at the proof,
I can make no sense of its last two sentences (containing
\eqref{ineq:2} and \eqref{ineq:3}). I seem to see at least three
logical holes in it, but I won't belabour the reader with what may
be only my misinterpretations.

Is the proof in the book valid, as it stands?  If so, a good answer
to this question might be a set of annotations spelling out the
points I have failed to understand (which I must imagine the authors
took to be 'obvious').

If there is indeed something wrong with it, can a simple edit restore
sense?  If so, such a suggested edit would also be a good answer.

(Corrections or improvements to my proof, or alternative proofs, would
also be welcome.)

---

In the light of Gio67's counterexample, consider adding a third
condition to the proposition:

> (iii) for every $n$, the image of $\gamma_n$ is nowhere dense.

In any topological space (not only a complete metric space, as in
the Baire Category Theorem), the intersection of two dense open sets
is dense; therefore the union of two nowhere dense sets is
nowhere dense; therefore the union of a finite number of nowhere
dense sets is nowhere dense. Therefore, for every $m \geq 2$, the
union $\Gamma$ of the images of
$\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \ldots, \gamma_{n_{m-1}}$ is nowhere dense.
It follows that we can choose $w \in \mathbb{U}^2$ such that
$|w - z| < 1/m$ and $w \notin \Gamma$. Because $\Gamma$ is closed,
$w$ has a neighbourhood that is disjoint from $\Gamma$ and contained
in the open ball with centre $z$ and radius $1/m$. By condition
(ii), we can find $\gamma_{n_m}(t_m)$ in this neighbourhood of $w$,
and \eqref{ineq:1} is satisfied, with $n_m > n_{m-1}$, as required.
$\square$

Comment: For condition (iii) to hold, a convenient sufficient condition (but not a necessary one) is that each $\gamma_n$ be rectifiable.  (See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69915) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70112).) In particular, it is enough if each $\gamma_n$ is piecewise continuously differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused. The way I read (ii) is 
$$\overline{\bigcup_n\gamma_n([0,1])}=\mathbb{U}^2,$$
but if this is the case, then I don't think the result is true.
Take $\gamma_1$ to be any continuous path such that $\gamma_1([0,1])=\mathbb{U}^2$, and then take $\gamma_n(t)=0$ for all $n\ge 2$ and all $t\in [0,1]$. Then properties (i) and (ii) are certainly satisfied but the limit is $\gamma=0$. In the proof what can happen is that $n_m=1$ for all $m$. 
 What am I missing?

Comment: +1 That looks good to me. My confidence in the truth of the proposition had been shaken by my failure to understand the proof, and I originally meant to include the question of its truth or falsity as part of my question, but in the end I was convinced enough by my own proof not to bother, although I still didn't feel entirely confident about any part of the business. Do you agree that my explicit assumption that $(n_m)_{m\geq1}$ is strictly increasing *does* imply that the image of $\gamma$ is $\mathbb{U}^2$, or might there be some further problem with the proposition and its "proofs"?

Comment: Yes if you could assume that the sequence is strictly increasing, then your proof works. Unfortunately hypothesis (ii) does not guarantee that.

Comment: A way to fix it is to assume instead of (ii) the stronger condition that for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $$\overline{\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty\gamma_n([0,1])}=\mathbb{U}^2.$$

Comment: I'll probably be accepting this answer in a couple of days' time. I've added a new section to the question, addressing your counterexample - you might want to check that out, too.

Comment: I just read it. Yes, hypothesis (iii) would prevent the counter-example and your proof would be complete. As for theirs, I agree that even if the sequence in (1) is strictly increasing, in general (2) is false. Since you have uniform convergence you know that $\gamma_{n_m}(t_n)\to\gamma (t_0)$ but you don't know the speed and so you cannot conclude that (2) holds.